# Php curl + https

Tags: php, curl, https, парсер

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо парсить несколько страниц с https://www.sravni.ru/, некоторое время назад скрипт перестал работать (раньше было **http**://www.sravni.ru/) но что ни делаю не могу получить страницу. Пробовал и запрещать проверку сертификатов и подставлял сертификат - результат в любом случае "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.sravni.ru:443 "
Один из вариантов ниже:

```
    function get_web_page($url)
{
        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);



        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);


 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_errno($ch);
        $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
        $header = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close( $ch );

        $header['errno']   = $err;
        $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
        $header['content'] = $content;

        return $header;
}
```

пробовалось такое:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

...и такое:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/www.sravni.ru.crt");
```

В какую сторону копать?

ЗЫ: php 5.4, ssl включен.
В каком то варианте получил один раз - Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2` вы уверены? Вообще добавлено куча ненужных опций

Comment: Не уверен... пробовал и 1 версию. Начинал с простого варианта с 3 строчек)

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас без проблем спарсил:

```
$url = 'https://www.sravni.ru/'; 
if($curl = curl_init()) { 
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30); 
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Bot 1.0');
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
echo $html;
```

PHP Version 5.6.27
curl 7.51.0

Comment: не парсится( Для пробы спарсил банки.ру и пару https страниц включая яндекс. Все норм но сравни.ру по прежнему возвращает false. Попробую поставить php 7, сейчас 5.4.29 и curl 7.36.0

Comment: c php7 тоже не пашет

Comment: Может банально в бане?

Comment: Как проверить? Из браузера страница открывается, из скрипта нет. Что странно из IE не открывается, только из фаерфокса.